# Preventing Safari prefetching web pages (server side)

Tags: http, safari, webserver

When typing a web link into the safari URL field, the browser attempts to prefetch all links it has previously seen before, both GET and POST.

This causes each and every web link a server supports that is listed in the dropdown as a possible completion to be activated. This is problematic. For example, if a web site has authentication with an /auth/logout link for logging out, then this can cause the link to be activated if it appears in the dropdown, logging the user out unintentionally.

Many browsers send a specific header (eg. 'Purpose: Prefetch' in chrome) that allows the server side to filter prefetch/preload requests (eg. return a 503) but Safari doesn't seem to send any distinguishing header field. It also seems to try to prefetch POST requests, which seems very broken to me. Get requests are notionally at least idempotent, but POST requests are supposed to be understood to be data changing.

1. Has anyone got a solution to this? Please don't suggest that the browser preload feature can be turned off by the end user - that ISN'T a solution from a service delivery perspective.
2. Has anyone got an explanation as to why browsers would do this and NOT signal the purpose in a header field? (I get why prefetching is a useful Ux capacity, but not why its useful while typing URLs, especially for URLs already previously downloaded and thus capable of returning prefetching metadata that would allow a server to selectively disable the capability where appropriate) From what I can tell, this kind of functionality started to appear with header fields included, but some browsers have removed this signature. why? It seems to be dreadfully broken to me.

thanks.